# Whitespace at the bottom of HTML page

Tags: html, css

In the middle of creating one of my first webpages for a college course and ran into a really weird problem. I've been commenting out code trying to find where the issue is but I have no idea what's wrong.

I used `*{ border: 1px solid red; }` to see all the CSS elements, and all I see that's related is a red line that outlines the entire page.

Any help? Here's my CSS.

```
h1 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:55px;
    
}

.gradPic{
    
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    
}

.titleBox {
    background-color:black;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:150px;
    width:1875px;
    position:static;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    
    
    
}


.bio {
    height:600px;
    width:400px;
    font-size:105%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    
    
}

.movies {
    height:600px;
    width:400px;
    font-size:105%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    position:relative;
    left:492px;
    bottom:625px;

}


.books {
    height:600px;
    width:400px;
    font-size:105%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    position:relative;
    left:984px;
    bottom:1250px;

}

.sites {
    height:600px;
    width:400px;
    font-size:105%;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    position:relative;
    left:1476px;
    bottom:1875px;
   
 
}


body {
    background-image: url("gradient.jpg");
    color:white
    
}
```

And the HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="StylesheetAssign2.css" type="text/css">
<title>Sujal's IT 130 Assignment 2 Page</title>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="titleBox"><h1>Sujal Dantluri</h1> <!-- box at the top of the page !-->
    
    
    
    </div>
    
    
     <div class="bio"><h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Personal Background</h2> <!-- personal info in unordered list !-->
         
         <img src="graduation.jpg" alt="Image couldn't be loaded; try again" height="175" width="225" class="gradPic"> <!-- creates a class for the image so it can be centered !-->
         
         <ul>
         <li>18 years old</li><br>
         <li>Majoring in Computer Science</li><br>    
         <li>Interested in Technology, Animals, and Cybersecurity</li><br>
         <li>Hobbies include an unhealthy amount of gaming and napping</li><br>
         <li>From Illinois</li><br>
         <li>Fun Fact: I have a twin sister.</li><br>   
         </ul>
        
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="movies"><h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Favorite Movies</h2>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="books"><h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Favorite Books</h2>
        
    </div> 
    
    <div class="sites"><h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Favorite Sites and Quotes</h2></div>
        
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: Are you talking about the white space around the body?

Comment: You're positioning things relative (which are vertically aligned), so it's still rendering in the normal flow but then moving them.

Comment: @possum how is this making the whitespace though? and is it the positioning code specifically causing it?

Comment: @GamersAgenda No, when I load the webpage in there is a huge amount of empty space at the bottom of everything else.

Comment: It's making the whitespace because it renders everything vertically and then moves them, leaving the whitespace.  You need to use something different than relative positioning if you want it to go away

Comment: @posssum Thank you. Would using absolute positioning cause any issues with the way I'm programming the site? I just tried it and it does remove the whitespace but I know the way I'm doing it is pretty inefficient and I'm not sure if it'll do anything down the line.

Comment: absolute positioning is annoying to manage later on, so I wouldn't reccomend it. also, dont set your img alt attribute to 'image couldn't be loaded', because if the user is using a screen reader, or Google wants to look at your page, they will think your website is about how to get images to load. yikes

Comment: @cornonthecob thanks! what would be good practice for alt text? also, if absolute positioning and relative positioning are annoying to manage when there is more complexity later on, what should I use to position divs? All my teacher has taught me so far are the types of position and the others don't seem like good replacements (sticky, fixed, etc.) static isnt affected by the directional commands either so I'm not sure what to do

Comment: For alt text, you should describe your image! For example, if there was a person on a bicycle with bread and grapes, you should add that as the alt text! For your absolute positioning question, because absolute positioning brings them out of the normal flow, you do have to write a lot of CSS. For one off things, it's fine, but it can get a lot to manage after a while

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
h1 {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:55px;
    
}

.gradPic{
    
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    
}

.titleBox {
    background-color:black;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    height:150px;
    width:100%;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    
    
    
}

.totaldiv{display:flex;width:100%;}
.bio {
display: inline-block;
    height:600px;
    width:25%;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    
    
}
.bio h2{margin: 0 0 10px;}
.movies {
display: inline-block;
    height:600px;
    width:25%;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    left:492px;
    bottom:625px;

}


.books {
display: inline-block;
    height:600px;
    width:25%;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    left:984px;
    bottom:1250px;

}

.sites {
display: inline-block;
    height:600px;
    width:25%;
    font-size:15px;
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background-color:black;
    border:5px outset white;
    border-style:groove;
    margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
    left:1476px;
    bottom:1875px;
   
 
}


body {
    background-image: url("gradient.jpg");
    color:white
    
}
```

```html
<div class="titleBox"><h1>Sujal Dantluri</h1> <!-- box at the top of the page !-->
    
    
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="totaldiv">
     <div class="bio"><h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Personal Background</h2> <!-- personal info in unordered list !-->
         
         <!--<img src="graduation.jpg" alt="Image couldn't be loaded; try again" height="175" width="225" class="gradPic">--> <!-- creates a class for the image so it can be centered !-->
         
         <ul>
         <li>18 years old</li><br>
         <li>Majoring in Computer Science</li><br>    
         <li>Interested in Technology, Animals, and Cybersecurity</li><br>
         <li>Hobbies include an unhealthy amount of gaming and napping</li><br>
         <li>From Illinois</li><br>
         <li>Fun Fact: I have a twin sister.</li><br>   
         </ul>
        
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="movies"><h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Favorite Movies</h2>
    
    </div>
    
    <div class="books"><h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Favorite Books</h2>
        
    </div> 
    
    <div class="sites"><h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Favorite Sites and Quotes</h2></div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is far from being useable for a real website (i.e. not repsponsive), but if you really want to fix such a width to the page, you should move the `width` setting from the header to the `body`, use `display: inline-block;` and `vertical-align: top;` on all those boxes that should be next to each other, and erase `position: relative` and all their `top`, `bottom`, left`and` right` settings. That way also the whitespace at the bottom will be history...

You can create spaces between the boxes by using `margin-left` on them, but there are better solutions like using a (full-width) container and applying `display: flex` and `justify-content: space-between` to it.

```css
h1 {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 55px;
}

.gradPic {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

.titleBox {
  background-color: black;
  height: 150px;
  position: static;
  border: 5px outset white;
  border-style: groove;
}

.bio {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 105%;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px outset white;
  border-style: groove;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.movies {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 105%;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px outset white;
  border-style: groove;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.books {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 105%;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px outset white;
  border-style: groove;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.sites {
  height: 600px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 105%;
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: black;
  border: 5px outset white;
  border-style: groove;
  margin: 15px 0px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

body {
  background-image: url("gradient.jpg");
  color: white;
  width: 1875px;

}
```

```html
<div class="titleBox">
  <h1>Sujal Dantluri</h1>
  <!-- box at the top of the page !-->
</div>


<div class="bio">
  <h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Personal Background</h2>
  <!-- personal info in unordered list !-->

  <img src="graduation.jpg" alt="Image couldn't be loaded; try again" height="175" width="225" class="gradPic">
  <!-- creates a class for the image so it can be centered !-->

  <ul>
    <li>18 years old</li><br>
    <li>Majoring in Computer Science</li><br>
    <li>Interested in Technology, Animals, and Cybersecurity</li><br>
    <li>Hobbies include an unhealthy amount of gaming and napping</li><br>
    <li>From Illinois</li><br>
    <li>Fun Fact: I have a twin sister.</li><br>
  </ul>

</div>


<div class="movies">
  <h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Favorite Movies</h2>

</div>

<div class="books">
  <h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Favorite Books</h2>

</div>

<div class="sites">
  <h2 style=color:white;text-align:center>Favorite Sites and Quotes</h2>
</div>
```